# Location and scale estimation for log-logistic in scipy

Tags: distributions, estimation, scipy, logistic-distribution

I have to estimate the location and scale parameters for a log-logistic or fisk distribution using scipy. The shape parameter is already defined and I would like to estimate loc and scale parameter having the mean and the standard deviation known a priori.

I don't want to fit these on the sample, because the mean and std are computed by a statistical model.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First of all, the correct reference is to the shifted version (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifted_log-logistic_distribution) which has the loc and scale parameters. And second I have tried to implement the method of moments with the wikipedia formulation and did not get the same resuls of scipy.